# How to get array value of v-model to an array object in script in Vue.Js?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuex

I have a dynamic input field that I can add and remove as per my requirement. But when I try to get the array value of the v-model to an object it displays undefined value. I can't get the array value of v-model in the template being in the script section.

Template Code

```
<div v-for="(record, index) in records" :key="record.name">
      <b-card style="margin-top:18px;">
        <span @click="remove(index)" v-if="index != 0">
          <strong>
            <b class="text-danger float-right">X</b>
          </strong>
        </span>
        <br />
        <b-form-group
          label-cols="12"
          label-cols-lg="3"
          label-for="input-1"
          label="Name: "
          label-align-sm="right"
          label-align="left"
        >
          <b-form-input
            id="input-1"
            v-model="record.name"
            type="text"
          ></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group
          label-cols="12"
          label-cols-lg="3"
          label-for="input-2"
          label="Order: "
          label-align-sm="right"
          label-align="left"
        >
          <b-form-input
            id="input-2"
            v-model="record.order"
            type="text"
          ></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>
      </b-card>
      <div>
        <span @click="add">
          <strong>
            <b class="text-success float-right">+</b>
          </strong>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Script code

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    update: false,
    records: [
      {
        name: "",
        order: ""
      }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    save(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      var object = {
        name: this.records.name,
        order: this.records.order
      };
      console.log(object);
    },

    add() {
      this.records.push({
        name: "",
        order: ""
      });
    },
    remove(index) {
      this.records.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I have tried the console.log to see if the data is displayed but it responds value of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to index your records array.

```
var object = {
        name: this.records[someIndex].name,
        order: this.records[someIndex].order
      };
```

Comment: I have tried indexing the fields but it does not work

Comment: @TesfuTekleab check this pen : https://codepen.io/cruz404/pen/oKvMdM?editors=1010

Comment: It is printing for me.  Vue wraps all data members in a reactive object.  Try to log this instead:  `console.log(JSON.stringify(object, 2, null))`; or this `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.records,2));`